# Can I get the device passcode to use as an encryption key?

Tags: ios, encryption

I'm working on encrypting core data with transformable attributes and have encryption/decryption working fine. My only issue is the actual key. Is there a way to get the devices passcode to use as an encryption key?

Comment: Only if the user gives it to you. Do you realize how bad it would be if 3rd party apps had access to the device's passcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access the device passcode from within an app. If you could that would be a major security flaw. Best option is for you to encrypt the data using a UUID generated for your application and stored on your keychain, or something of the sort.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to go the CFUUID route

Comment: Better to just get random bytes.